# Table css is messing up on shrinking the window

Tags: css, html-table, flexbox, css-selectors, css-position

My code is working fine and displaying the tables with css well applied but when I am shrinking the window table is getting messed up with different columns taking up different space (I have attached in screenshot). Basically I want the first column which is without the checkbox to be intact(sticky) and rest columns to take equal space with a scroll enabled when I shrink the window . How do I fix that up, Can anyone please help?

Is there any way I keep the table container width as it is there in desktop view and just put a scroller in the mobile view with first column fixed and not shrink the tables?

like in this example https://codepen.io/paulobrien/pen/LBrMxa

```css
        .hero-button {
            padding: 27px;
            cursor: pointer;
            text-decoration: none !important;
        }

        a .hero-button1 {
            min-height: 36px;
            letter-spacing: normal;
            border-width: 2px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            border-image: initial;
            border-radius: 25px;
            padding: 6px 50px;
            text-decoration: none;

            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 14px;
            color: #fff;
            font-weight: 600;
            letter-spacing: 3px;
            margin: 35px 0 0;
        }

        input {
            color: black;
        }

        .table_container {
            float: left;
            width: 30rem;
            margin-bottom: 3rem;
        }

        .table_container2 {
            float: left;
            width: 30rem;
            margin-bottom: 3rem;
        }

        .container {
            width: 100%;
            margin-top: 30px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center
        }

        .container2 {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        .checkcontainer {
            width: 100%;
        }

        .container::after {
            content: "";
            clear: both;
            display: table;
        }

        table {
            margin: 2rem auto;
            border-radius: 10px;
        }

        tr {
            padding: 15px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        td {
            color: black;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
            height: 60px;
            background-color: #e1edf9;
            width: 272px;
            border-top: 1px solid white;
        }



        .sub_text {
            font-size: 12px;
            font-style: italic;
            color: #003a6a;
            font-weight: 100;
        }

        th {
            background-color: #003a6a;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
            /*border-top-left-radius: 10px;*/
            /*border-top-right-radius: 10px;*/
            color: white;
            font-weight: bold;
            height: 75px;
        }

        .header {
            color: #003a6a;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding: 10px;
            border-right: 1px solid white;
        }

        .wrapper {
            margin-top: 20px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        .modal-content {
            top: 50% !important;
            position: fixed !important;
        }

        table tr:last-child td:first-child {
            /*border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;*/
        }

        table tr:last-child td:last-child {
            /*  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;*/
        }

        @media screen and (min-width: 1400px) {
            .table_container {
                float: left;
                width: 15rem;
            }

            .table_container:first-of-type {
                width: 30rem;
            }
        }

        @media screen and (min-width: 1400px) {
            .table_container2 {
                float: left;
                width: 15rem;
            }

            .table_container2:first-of-type {
                width: 30rem;
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (min-width: 1000) and (max-device-width: 1400px) {
            .table_container2 {
                float: left;
                width: 14rem;
            }

            .table_container2:first-of-type {
                width: 27rem;
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (min-width: 1000) and (max-device-width: 1400px) {
            .table_container {
                float: left;
                width: 14rem;
            }

            .table_container:first-of-type {
                width: 27rem;
            }
        }

        .checks {
            height: 20px;
            background-color: #003A6A;
            border-top: none;
        }

        .parent_container {

            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #modalButton {
            background-color: #003A6A;
        }
```

```html
<div class="parent_container">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="table_container">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="2">Cost</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                    </thead>
                    
                        <td class="header" rowspan="4">Your cost per biweekly paycheck<br>
                            <span class="sub_text">Tobacco-free rates shown</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>employee Only</td>
                    <tr>
                        <td>employee + Spouse/partner</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>employee + child(ren)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>employee + family</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="header" rowspan="2">Annual max contribution<br>
                            <span class="sub_text">
                            </span>
                        </td>
                        <td>employee Only</td>
                    <tr>
                        <td>employee + dependent(s)</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="header" rowspan="2">Annua deductible<br>
                            <span class="sub_text">in-network care</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>employee Only</td>
                    <tr>
                        <td>employee + dependent(s)</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="header" rowspan="2">Annual out-of-pocket maximum<br>
                            <span class="sub_text">in-network care</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>Per person</td>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Entire family</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tr>
                </table>
    
            </div>
    
            <div class="table_container">
                <table id="table1" class="checkboxdiv">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Saver Plan NW <input type="checkbox" id=" 1" name="table1" value="table1"
                                    onchange="myFunction(event)"> </th>
        
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    
                    <tr>
                        <td>$133.90</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>$161.30</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>$53.30</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>$186.20</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>$4 after deductible
$50 or 25% of allowed cost* after deductible</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>HSA match:up to $700</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>$50 or 20% of allowed cost* after deductible
</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>$6000</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>$6650</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>$13300</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
    
            <div class="table_container">
                <table id="table2" class="checkboxdiv">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Saver Plan <input type="checkbox" id="2" name="table2" value="table2"
                                    onchange="myFunction(event)"></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    
                    <tr>
                        <td>$33.90</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>$161.30</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>$53.30</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>$186.20</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>HSA match:up to $350</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>HSA match:up to $700</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>$3000</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>$6000</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>$660</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>$13300</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
    
            <div class="table_container">
                <table id="table3" class="checkboxdiv">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Saver Plan SW <input type="checkbox" id="3" name="table3" value="table3"
                                    onchange="myFunction(event)"> </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    
                    <tr>
                        <td>$33.90</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>$161.30</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>$53.30</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>$186.20</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>HSA match:up to $350</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>HSA match:up to $700</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>$3000</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>$60</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>$660</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>$10</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container2">
            <div class="table_container">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="2">Cost</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                    </thead>
                    
                        <td class="header" rowspan="4">Your cost per biweekly paycheck<br>
                            <span class="sub_text">Tobacco-free rates shown</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>employee Only</td>
                    <tr>
                        <td>employee + Spouse/partner</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>employee + child(ren)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>employee + family</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="header" rowspan="2">Annual max contribution<br>
                            <span class="sub_text">
                            </span>
                        </td>
                        <td>employee Only</td>
                    <tr>
                        <td>employee + dependent(s)</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="header" rowspan="2">Annua deductible<br>
                            <span class="sub_text">in-network care</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>employee Only</td>
                    <tr>
                        <td>employee + dependent(s)</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="header" rowspan="2">Annual out-of-pocket maximum<br>
                            <span class="sub_text">in-network care</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>Per person</td>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Entire family</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tr>
                </table>
    
            </div>
    
            <div class="table_container">
                <table id="table1" class="checkboxdiv">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Saver Plan NW Arkansas <input type="checkbox" id=" 1" name="table1" value="table1"
                                    onchange="myFunction(event)"> </th>
        
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    
                    <tr>
                        <td>$133.90</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>$161.30</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>$53.30</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>$186.20</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>HSA match:up to $350</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>HSA match:up to $700</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>$3000</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>$6000</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>$6650</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>$13300</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
    
            <div class="table_container">
                <table id="table2" class="checkboxdiv">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Saver Plan NW Arkansas <input type="checkbox" id="2" name="table2" value="table2"
                                    onchange="myFunction(event)"></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    
                    <tr>
                        <td>$33.90</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>$161.30</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>$53.30</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>$186.20</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>HSA match:up to $350</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>HSA match:up to $700</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>$3000</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>$6000</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>$660</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>$13300</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
    
            <div class="table_container">
                <table id="table3" class="checkboxdiv">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Saver Plan NW Arkansas <input type="checkbox" id="3" name="table3" value="table3"
                                    onchange="myFunction(event)"> </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    
                    <tr>
                        <td>$33.90</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>$161.30</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>$53.30</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>$186.20</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>HSA match:up to $350</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>HSA match:up to $700</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>$3000</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>$60</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>$660</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>$10</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <button type="button" id="modalButton" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="javascript: return false;" >
                Click me
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: looks like the trouble is that you have not a single table, but a few  overflowing  their containers. You should rethink the whole structure from a single table (colspan/rowspan it seems like you handle them fine).

Comment: yes thats not a single table but multiple tables, when I am receiving data they are getting populated

Comment: okay, remove all the width you do reset and let it overflow then :(  example with max-content to keep every thing aligned : https://jsfiddle.net/pdh5yz3o/  You may restart from there

Comment: You should remove "max-device-width" from your media queries and replace them with "max-width" and also change "min-width:1000" to "min-width:1000px" in those media queries.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Thanks but this doesnt seem to be working

Comment: that was a restart from , not solving your problem. But maybe you have to think over the template you use to retrieve your datas .Maybe the restart from should be from how you recieve your datas .

Comment: @G-Cyrillus -> restart from as in? I dint get you

Comment: nested tables is obviously your trouble, the fiddle is back to a base where it seems okay with width removed everywhere in the mediaqueries , where you can try others CSS method while resizing your tables. But i think you should probably rethink the template used to retrieve your datas,, i do not know, maybe stocking your datas in an array before starting building a single table. I do not think CSS is your answer here. Sorry not help you that much.

Comment: Is there any way I keep the table container  width as it is there in desktop and just put a scroller in the mobile view and not shrink the tables?

Comment: So you can't change the HTML disposition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made the table responsive in such a way that when the screen size reduces the table would retain its original dimensions but the scrollbar would appear in x and y directions(Thats what I read in your comment) I just did this for one table.

What I did was encapsulate the `.container` class with `.parent_container`
and gave it following css

```
.parent_container{
    max-width: 844px;
    height: 733px;
    overflow:auto;
width: 100%;
}
```

here I calculated the width and height of `.parent_container` by using inspect tool.

Also I provided a min-width to the `table` so that the it won't shrink when screen size reduces.

#### This will work for u

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.parent_container {
  max-height: 1164px;
  max-width: 1181px;
  width: 90%;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0px 20px;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  min-width: 220px;
  text-align: center;
}

.left_column td {
  min-width: 110px;
}

td {
  background: #E1EDF9;
}

th {
  background: #003A6A;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.left_column {
  position: sticky;
  width: 250px;
  left: 0;
}

.side_header {
  color: #003A6A;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.side_header span {
  font-weight: normal;
}

span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
}

tr table tr td {
  min-width: 220px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent_container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2" style="position: sticky;left: 0;z-index: 10000;">
          Cost
        </th>
        <th>
          Saver Plan NW
          <input type="checkbox" name="">
        </th>
        <th>
          Saver Plan
          <input type="checkbox" name="">
        </th>
        <th>
          Saver Plan SW
          <input type="checkbox" name="">
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="left_column" colspan="2" rowspan="4" style="padding: 0px">
          <table style="">
            <tr>
              <td rowspan="5" class="side_header">
                Your cost per biweekly paycheck <span>Tobacco-free rates shown</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>employee Only</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>employee + Spouse/partner</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>employee + child(ren)</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>employee + family</td>
            </tr>
          </table>


        </td>
        <td>$133.90</td>
        <td>$33.90</td>
        <td>$33.90</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>$161.30</td>
        <td>$161.30</td>
        <td>$161.30</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>$53.30</td>
        <td>$53.30</td>
        <td>$53.30</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>$186.20</td>
        <td>$186.20</td>
        <td>$186.20</td>
      </tr>


      <tr>
        <td class="left_column" colspan="2" rowspan="2" style="padding: 0px;">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td rowspan="3" class="side_header">
                Annual max contribution
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-top: 30px">employee Only</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-bottom: 30px">employee + dependent(s)</td>
            </tr>
          </table>


        </td>
        <td>$4 after deductible $50 or 25% of allowed cost* after deductible</td>
        <td>HSA match:up to $350</td>
        <td>HSA match:up to $350</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>HSA match:up to $700</td>
        <td>HSA match:up to $700</td>
        <td>HSA match:up to $700</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="left_column" colspan="2" rowspan="2" style="padding: 0px;">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td rowspan="3" class="side_header">
                Annua deductible<span>in-network care</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-top: 30px">employee Only</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-top: 30px">employee + dependent(s)</td>
            </tr>
          </table>


        </td>
        <td>$50 or 20% of allowed cost* after deductible</td>
        <td>$3000</td>
        <td>$3000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>$6000</td>
        <td>$6000</td>
        <td>$60</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="left_column" colspan="2" rowspan="2" style="padding: 0px;">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td rowspan="3" class="side_header">
                Annual out-of-pocket maximum <span>in-network care</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Per person</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Entire family</td>
            </tr>
          </table>


        </td>
        <td>$6650</td>
        <td>$660</td>
        <td>$660</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>$13300</td>
        <td>$13300</td>
        <td>$10</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>


<div class="parent_container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2" style="position: sticky;left: 0;z-index: 10000;">
          Cost
        </th>
        <th>
          Saver Plan NW
          <input type="checkbox" name="">
        </th>
        <th>
          Saver Plan
          <input type="checkbox" name="">
        </th>
        <th>
          Saver Plan SW
          <input type="checkbox" name="">
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="left_column" colspan="2" rowspan="4" style="padding: 0px">
          <table style="">
            <tr>
              <td rowspan="5" class="side_header">
                Your cost per biweekly paycheck <span>Tobacco-free rates shown</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>employee Only</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>employee + Spouse/partner</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>employee + child(ren)</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>employee + family</td>
            </tr>
          </table>


        </td>
        <td>$133.90</td>
        <td>$33.90</td>
        <td>$33.90</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>$161.30</td>
        <td>$161.30</td>
        <td>$161.30</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>$53.30</td>
        <td>$53.30</td>
        <td>$53.30</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>$186.20</td>
        <td>$186.20</td>
        <td>$186.20</td>
      </tr>


      <tr>
        <td class="left_column" colspan="2" rowspan="2" style="padding: 0px;">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td rowspan="3" class="side_header">
                Annual max contribution
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-top: 30px">employee Only</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-bottom: 30px">employee + dependent(s)</td>
            </tr>
          </table>


        </td>
        <td>$4 after deductible $50 or 25% of allowed cost* after deductible</td>
        <td>HSA match:up to $350</td>
        <td>HSA match:up to $350</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>HSA match:up to $700</td>
        <td>HSA match:up to $700</td>
        <td>HSA match:up to $700</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="left_column" colspan="2" rowspan="2" style="padding: 0px;">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td rowspan="3" class="side_header">
                Annua deductible<span>in-network care</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-top: 30px">employee Only</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-top: 30px">employee + dependent(s)</td>
            </tr>
          </table>


        </td>
        <td>$50 or 20% of allowed cost* after deductible</td>
        <td>$3000</td>
        <td>$3000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>$6000</td>
        <td>$6000</td>
        <td>$60</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="left_column" colspan="2" rowspan="2" style="padding: 0px;">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td rowspan="3" class="side_header">
                Annual out-of-pocket maximum <span>in-network care</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Per person</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Entire family</td>
            </tr>
          </table>


        </td>
        <td>$6650</td>
        <td>$660</td>
        <td>$660</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>$13300</td>
        <td>$13300</td>
        <td>$10</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for it but it is modifying the table when the screen is normal desktop version aswell. I want that to be untouched

Comment: @ShilpiDhiman i cannot see a change will you be more specific ?do you want the full desktop version of table with no scrollbar

Comment: yes I want the full version whithout scroll bar because the entire data is visible without the need of adding a scrollbar. I only need scrollbar once user is on mobile view

Comment: so if you will see the screen with this css change it moves to the left on desktop view but with my current code it is in the center of the screen with full width

Comment: and also the left most column is also moving, it should be sticky when scrolling is done.

Comment: @ShilpiDhiman Are you talking about this column where it is written `Your cost per biweekly paycheck
Tobacco-free rates shown` rest i have edited

Comment: Yes that one only

Comment: https://codepen.io/paulobrien/pen/LBrMxa something like this example

Comment: @sd_30 I have edited the code again see if it works for you

Comment: what changes did u do to remove scroll from desktop version, coz when i am trying to use this code it gives me the scroll

Comment: @sd_30 You can see in `.parent_container` that I have defined the dimensions of the table what basically i did was use inspect tool and gave the height and width based on it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232227/discussion-between-sd-30-and-ac-mmi).

Answer (score 1):

So a lot of your problems came from using CSS versus HTML to format what you're table looked like. If you put it all into one table and then use CSS to enhance it, you run into a lot less problems. I redid your HTML and used the same CSS and it works fine. You will most likely want to remove a lot of those styles because they aren't necessary.

DEMO:

```css
.hero-button {
  padding: 27px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

a .hero-button1 {
  min-height: 36px;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-image: initial;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 6px 50px;
  text-decoration: none;

  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  margin: 35px 0 0;
}

input {
  color: black;
}

.table_container {
  float: left;
  width: 30rem;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

.table_container2 {
  float: left;
  width: 30rem;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center
}

.container2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.checkcontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.container::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

table {
  margin: 2rem auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

tr {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #e1edf9;
  width: 272px;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
}



.sub_text {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #003a6a;
  font-weight: 100;
}

th {
  background-color: #003a6a;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
  /*border-top-left-radius: 10px;*/
  /*border-top-right-radius: 10px;*/
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 75px;
}

.header {
  color: #003a6a;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
}

.wrapper {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.modal-content {
  top: 50% !important;
  position: fixed !important;
}

table tr:last-child td:first-child {
  /*border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;*/
}

table tr:last-child td:last-child {
  /*  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;*/
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1400px) {
  .table_container {
    float: left;
    width: 15rem;
  }

  .table_container:first-of-type {
    width: 30rem;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1400px) {
  .table_container2 {
    float: left;
    width: 15rem;
  }

  .table_container2:first-of-type {
    width: 30rem;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000) and (max-device-width: 1400px) {
  .table_container2 {
    float: left;
    width: 14rem;
  }

  .table_container2:first-of-type {
    width: 27rem;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000) and (max-device-width: 1400px) {
  .table_container {
    float: left;
    width: 14rem;
  }

  .table_container:first-of-type {
    width: 27rem;
  }
}

.checks {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #003A6A;
  border-top: none;
}

.parent_container {

  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#modalButton {
  background-color: #003A6A;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Cost
      </th>
      <th>Saver Plan NW <input type="checkbox" id="1" name="table1" value="table1" onchange="myFunction(event)">
      </th>
      <th>Saver Plan <input type="checkbox" id="2" name="table2" value="table2" onchange="myFunction(event)">
      </th>
      <th>Saver Plan SW <input type="checkbox" id="3" name="table3" value="table3" onchange="myFunction(event)">
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td class="header" rowspan="4">Your cost per biweekly paycheck<br>
      <span class="sub_text">Tobacco-free rates shown</span>
    </td>
    <td>employee Only</td>
    <td>$133.90</td>
    <td>$33.90</td>
    <td>$33.90</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>employee + Spouse/partner</td>
    <td>$161.30</td>
    <td>$161.30</td>
    <td>$161.30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>employee + child(ren)</td>
    <td>$53.30</td>
    <td>$53.30</td>
    <td>$53.30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>employee + family</td>
    <td>$186.20</td>
    <td>$186.20</td>
    <td>$186.20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="header" rowspan="2">Annual max contribution<br>
      <span class="sub_text">
      </span>
    <td>employee Only</td>
    <td>$4 after deductible $50 or 25% of allowed cost* after deductible</td>
    <td>HSA match:up to $350</td>
    <td>HSA match:up to $350</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>employee + dependent(s)</td>
    <td>HSA match:up to $700</td>
    <td>HSA match:up to $700</td>
    <td>HSA match:up to $700</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="header" rowspan="2">Annua deductible<br>
      <span class="sub_text">in-network care</span>
    </td>
    <td>employee Only</td>
    <td>$50 or 20% of allowed cost* after deductible</td>
    <td>$3000</td>
    <td>$3000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>employee + dependent(s)</td>
    <td>$6000</td>
    <td>$6000</td>
    <td>$60</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="header" rowspan="2">Annual out-of-pocket maximum<br>
      <span class="sub_text">in-network care</span>
    </td>
    <td>Per person</td>
    <td>$6650</td>
    <td>$660</td>
    <td>$660</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Entire family</td>
    <td>$13300</td>
    <td>$13300</td>
    <td>$10</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Cost
      </th>
      <th>Saver Plan NW Arkansas <input type="checkbox" id="1" name="table1" value="table1"
          onchange="myFunction(event)">
      </th>
      <th>Saver Plan NW Arkansas <input type="checkbox" id="2" name="table2" value="table2"
          onchange="myFunction(event)">
      </th>
      <th>Saver Plan NW Arkansas <input type="checkbox" id="3" name="table3" value="table3"
          onchange="myFunction(event)">
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td class="header" rowspan="4">Your cost per biweekly paycheck<br>
      <span class="sub_text">Tobacco-free rates shown</span>
    </td>
    <td>employee Only</td>
    <td>$133.90</td>
    <td>$33.90</td>
    <td>$33.90</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>employee + Spouse/partner</td>
    <td>$161.30</td>
    <td>$161.30</td>
    <td>$161.30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>employee + child(ren)</td>
    <td>$53.30</td>
    <td>$53.30</td>
    <td>$53.30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>employee + family</td>
    <td>$186.20</td>
    <td>$186.20</td>
    <td>$186.20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="header" rowspan="2">Annual max contribution<br>
      <span class="sub_text">
      </span>
    <td>employee Only</td>
    <td>HSA match:up to $350</td>
    <td>HSA match:up to $350</td>
    <td>HSA match:up to $350</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>employee + dependent(s)</td>
    <td>HSA match:up to $700</td>
    <td>HSA match:up to $700</td>
    <td>HSA match:up to $700</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="header" rowspan="2">Annua deductible<br>
      <span class="sub_text">in-network care</span>
    </td>
    <td>employee Only</td>
    <td>$3000</td>
    <td>$3000</td>
    <td>$3000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>employee + dependent(s)</td>
    <td>$6000</td>
    <td>$6000</td>
    <td>$60</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="header" rowspan="2">Annual out-of-pocket maximum<br>
      <span class="sub_text">in-network care</span>
    </td>
    <td>Per person</td>
    <td>$6650</td>
    <td>$660</td>
    <td>$660</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Entire family</td>
    <td>$13300</td>
    <td>$13300</td>
    <td>$10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That is obviously the best, but as he mentionned in his comment below question **_"thats not a single table but multiple tables, when I am receiving data they are getting populated"_** So not sure that he can compile it all in the same table

Comment: Sure depending on the techniques used in his JS, he may run into the issue of re-populating the data or have to add certain ID's/Classes in order to fix that issue. That could be made into another thread if so. I just wanted to offer a solution to the issue posted, which has to do with style of the page and its responsiveness.

Comment: You can see in his example that some of the rows aren't aligned perfectly either because of the different tables. This would fix most layout/style issues while using cleaner CSS/HTML. I agree though, it would then just be an issue of populating and how you'd want to go about that.

Comment: I saw that, this is why I offered a solution with js that fix the problem, without touching html / css. But still, your solution would be the best, if he can populate correctly

Comment: I am not sure how this gonna work since I am creating the tables as and when I am getting data. So basically I am putting a conditional statement if that is true the corresponding json gets converted into a table.

Comment: The code that i have put is just to give a refrence how my final tabels are looking

Comment: So basically for the mobile version I was expecting something like this https://codepen.io/paulobrien/pen/LBrMxa ? Any help on that?

Comment: Is there a way to have the json convert each data item into an individual row instead of creating an entire table? Similar to how you would work with a php file

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do much only with css as you are trying to make 4 table fit next to each other.

I would recommand you to use jQuery. After you can add this code in `ready`and `resize` event to make sure that the height will be adapted correctly.

### Demo:

```js
var highestThead;
var arrayTR = [];

$(window).resize(resizeHeight);

$(document).ready(resizeHeight);


function resizeHeight(){
  /* Loop to get the highest tr and store it to the array */
  $(".table_container").each(function(){

    if($(this).find("thead tr").innerHeight() > highestThead){
      highestThead = $(this).find("thead tr").innerHeight();
    }
    var allTR = $(this).find("tbody tr");

    for (i = 0; i < allTR.length; i++) {
      if(arrayTR[i] == undefined || $(allTR[i]).innerHeight() > arrayTR[i]){
        arrayTR[i] = $(allTR[i]).innerHeight();
      }
    }
  });

  /* Loop to set the highest tr to the whole tr  */
  $(".table_container").each(function(){
    $(this).find("thead tr").css("height", highestThead+"px");

    var allTR = $(this).find("tbody tr");

    for (i = 0; i < allTR.length; i++) {
      $(allTR[i]).css("height", arrayTR[i]+"px");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.hero-button {
    padding: 27px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

a .hero-button1 {
    min-height: 36px;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-image: initial;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 6px 50px;
    text-decoration: none;

    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    margin: 35px 0 0;
}

input {
    color: black;
}

.table_container {
    float: left;
    width: 30rem;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

.table_container2 {
    float: left;
    width: 30rem;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center
}

.container2 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.checkcontainer {
    width: 100%;
}

.container::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

table {
    margin: 2rem auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

tr {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

td {
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #e1edf9;
    width: 272px;
    border-top: 1px solid white;
}



.sub_text {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #003a6a;
    font-weight: 100;
}

th {
    background-color: #003a6a;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    /*border-top-left-radius: 10px;*/
    /*border-top-right-radius: 10px;*/
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 75px;
}

.header {
    color: #003a6a;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
}

.wrapper {
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.modal-content {
    top: 50% !important;
    position: fixed !important;
}

table tr:last-child td:first-child {
    /*border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;*/
}

table tr:last-child td:last-child {
    /*  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;*/
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1400px) {
    .table_container {
        float: left;
        width: 15rem;
    }

    .table_container:first-of-type {
        width: 30rem;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1400px) {
    .table_container2 {
        float: left;
        width: 15rem;
    }

    .table_container2:first-of-type {
        width: 30rem;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000) and (max-device-width: 1400px) {
    .table_container2 {
        float: left;
        width: 14rem;
    }

    .table_container2:first-of-type {
        width: 27rem;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000) and (max-device-width: 1400px) {
    .table_container {
        float: left;
        width: 14rem;
    }

    .table_container:first-of-type {
        width: 27rem;
    }
}

.checks {
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #003A6A;
    border-top: none;
}

.parent_container {

    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#modalButton {
    background-color: #003A6A;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent_container">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="table_container">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2">Cost</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                    <td class="header" rowspan="4">Your cost per biweekly paycheck<br>
                        <span class="sub_text">Tobacco-free rates shown</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>employee Only</td>
                <tr>
                    <td>employee + Spouse/partner</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>employee + child(ren)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>employee + family</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="header" rowspan="2">Annual max contribution<br>
                        <span class="sub_text">
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td>employee Only</td>
                <tr>
                    <td>employee + dependent(s)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="header" rowspan="2">Annua deductible<br>
                        <span class="sub_text">in-network care</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>employee Only</td>
                <tr>
                    <td>employee + dependent(s)</td>
                </tr>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="header" rowspan="2">Annual out-of-pocket maximum<br>
                        <span class="sub_text">in-network care</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>Per person</td>
                <tr>
                    <td>Entire family</td>
                </tr>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>

        <div class="table_container">
            <table id="table1" class="checkboxdiv">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Saver Plan NW <input type="checkbox" id=" 1" name="table1" value="table1"
                                onchange="myFunction(event)"> </th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tr>
                    <td>$133.90</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$161.30</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$53.30</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$186.20</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$4 after deductible
$50 or 25% of allowed cost* after deductible</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>HSA match:up to $700</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$50 or 20% of allowed cost* after deductible
</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$6000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$6650</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$13300</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="table_container">
            <table id="table2" class="checkboxdiv">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Saver Plan <input type="checkbox" id="2" name="table2" value="table2"
                                onchange="myFunction(event)"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tr>
                    <td>$33.90</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$161.30</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$53.30</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$186.20</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>HSA match:up to $350</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>HSA match:up to $700</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$3000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$6000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$660</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$13300</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="table_container">
            <table id="table3" class="checkboxdiv">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Saver Plan SW <input type="checkbox" id="3" name="table3" value="table3"
                                onchange="myFunction(event)"> </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tr>
                    <td>$33.90</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$161.30</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$53.30</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$186.20</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>HSA match:up to $350</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>HSA match:up to $700</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$3000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$60</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$660</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$10</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container2">
        <div class="table_container">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2">Cost</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                </thead>

                    <td class="header" rowspan="4">Your cost per biweekly paycheck<br>
                        <span class="sub_text">Tobacco-free rates shown</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>employee Only</td>
                <tr>
                    <td>employee + Spouse/partner</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>employee + child(ren)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>employee + family</td>
                </tr>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="header" rowspan="2">Annual max contribution<br>
                        <span class="sub_text">
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td>employee Only</td>
                <tr>
                    <td>employee + dependent(s)</td>
                </tr>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="header" rowspan="2">Annua deductible<br>
                        <span class="sub_text">in-network care</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>employee Only</td>
                <tr>
                    <td>employee + dependent(s)</td>
                </tr>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="header" rowspan="2">Annual out-of-pocket maximum<br>
                        <span class="sub_text">in-network care</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>Per person</td>
                <tr>
                    <td>Entire family</td>
                </tr>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>

        <div class="table_container">
            <table id="table1" class="checkboxdiv">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Saver Plan NW Arkansas <input type="checkbox" id=" 1" name="table1" value="table1"
                                onchange="myFunction(event)"> </th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tr>
                    <td>$133.90</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$161.30</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$53.30</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$186.20</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>HSA match:up to $350</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>HSA match:up to $700</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$3000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$6000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$6650</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$13300</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="table_container">
            <table id="table2" class="checkboxdiv">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Saver Plan NW Arkansas <input type="checkbox" id="2" name="table2" value="table2"
                                onchange="myFunction(event)"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tr>
                    <td>$33.90</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$161.30</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$53.30</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$186.20</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>HSA match:up to $350</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>HSA match:up to $700</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$3000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$6000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$660</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$13300</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="table_container">
            <table id="table3" class="checkboxdiv">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Saver Plan NW Arkansas <input type="checkbox" id="3" name="table3" value="table3"
                                onchange="myFunction(event)"> </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tr>
                    <td>$33.90</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$161.30</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$53.30</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$186.20</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>HSA match:up to $350</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>HSA match:up to $700</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$3000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$60</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$660</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$10</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <button type="button" id="modalButton" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="javascript: return false;" >
            Click me
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont get the read and resize event , could you please clarify it?

Comment: Just the 2 lines I added in jquery like: `$(window).resize(resizeHeight);

$(document).ready(resizeHeight);` to make sure if you try to resize your screen, calcul is made again

Comment: No it did not..tables are messing up again